# Remove a section in config file using bash

Tags: bash

Am still a newbie in scripting. I am trying to write a script to remove a section from a config file, I have tried writing several scripts from different posts from the website here but not successful till the moment.

Sample of config file:

```
[inbound-customerA]
exten => _XXXXXXXXXXX,1,Macro(setuser,customerA)
exten => _XXXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/customerA/${EXTEN})
exten => XXXXXXXXXXX,1,Macro(setuser,customerA)
exten => XXXXXXXXXXX,n,Set(CHANNEL(amaflags)=billing)
exten => XXXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/customerA/${EXTEN})

[inbound-customerB]
exten => XXXXXXXXXXX,1,ExecIf($[ "${CALLERID(name):0:2}" = "61" ]? 
Set(CALLERID(name)=0${CALLERID(name):2}))
exten => XXXXXXXXXXX,n,ExecIf($[ "${CALLERID(num):0:2}" = "61" ]? 
Set(CALLERID(num)=0${CALLERID(num):2}))
exten => XXXXXXXXXXX,1,Macro(setuser,CustomerB)
exten => XXXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/CustomerB/${EXTEN})
```

so what i need to do exactly is delete only the section for CustomerA

The below was my approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
File_path="/home/xx/xxx_test/extensions.conf"
cp "$File_path" "$File_path".bak
IFS='
 '
 PATTERN_1="[inbound\-customerA]"
 PATTERN_2="(SIP/customerA/${EXTEN})"

 GREP_RESULTS=(`grep -nRi "$PATTERN_1" "$File_path"`)


for line in "${GREP_RESULTS[@]}"; do
FILE=${line%%:*} START_LINE=echo "$line" | cut -f2 -d:

  GREP_RESULT=(`tail -n +${START_LINE} $FILE | grep -in "$PATTERN_2" | head -n1`)
END_LINE="$(( $START_LINE + echo "$GREP_RESULT" | cut -f1 -d: - 1 ))"

sed -e "${START_LINE},${END_LINE}d;" $FILE > $FILE done
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Could you please do let me know if this solution has helped you?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok with `awk` you could try following. Written and tested it https://ideone.com/eMe3nO

```
awk '
/^\[inbound/{
  if($0~/inbound-customerA/){
    found=1
  }
  else{
    found=""
  }
}
!found
' Input_file
```